# sed command in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to find the USB PORT of the device connected to the machine. I used the command

```
dmseg | grep "ttyUSB" | grep "attached"
```

I got the output as

```
[  525.763315] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  525.796039] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

But I need the port only. SO I used the command

```
cut -d ' ' -f14
```

I got

```
ttyUSB0
ttyUSB1
```

I want to replace the value of a file  with this output.So i used the se command

```
sed -i "s/\b\SERIAL_INTERFACE=\b.*/SERIAL_INTERFACE=$(dmesg | grep "ttyUSB" | grep "attached" | cut -d ' ' -f13)/g" /home/ubuntu/webserver/properties.cfg
```

But it shows the error
sed: -e expression #1, char 46: unterminated `s' command

Help me to figure out this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are using double quotes to delimit the argument to sed and also using double quotes inside the expression.

Comment: try escaping the double quotes

Comment: Provide your sample input file and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
sed -i "s/\b\SERIAL_INTERFACE=\b.*/SERIAL_INTERFACE=$(dmesg | grep "ttyUSB" | grep "attached" | cut -d ' ' -f13)/g" /home/ubuntu/webserver/properties.cfg
```

with:

```
sed -i "s/\bSERIAL_INTERFACE=\b.*/SERIAL_INTERFACE=$(dmesg | grep "ttyUSB" | grep "attached" | cut -d ' ' -f14| tr '\n' ' ' | tee save.tmp)/g" /home/ubuntu/webserver
```

The problem was that the pipeline produced multiple output lines.  The solution is to add `tr '\n' ' '` to remove the newlines.

Four other comments:

- The `S` in SERIAL_INTERFACE was escaped for no apparent reason.  I removed that escape.
- You reported success with the command `cut -d ' ' -f14` but the pipeline command used `cut -d ' ' -f13`.
- As mentioned in the comments, you do have quotes within quotes but that is just fine: the inner quotes are inside of `$(...)` and thus do not interfere with the outer quotes.
- The output of this command looks like:

  ```
  SERIAL_INTERFACE=ttyUSB0 ttyUSB1
  ```

  Since you haven't said what your desired output is, I don't know if this is what you want or not.

#### Why the "unterminated `s` command" error?

Suppose we have a shell variable that contains a newline:

```
$ echo "$string"
a
b
```

When you substitute this variable into a sed command, sed sees the newline character as terminating a line which terminates the command.  The result is an "unterminated `s` command":

```
$ echo hi | sed "s/hi/$string"
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

By contrast, without the newline character, it works fine:

```
$ string="a b"
$ echo hi | sed "s/hi/$string/"
a b
```

In summary, when substituting shell variables into `sed` commands, one has to be very careful.